# Passing Arguments: MIPS

Tags: function, arguments, mips

I'd like to pass a character as an argument to a function in MIPS.  Do I do this by storing the character into register $a0, use jal to move to the function, then extract what's in $a0 into a separate register using lw?

If someone could give me an example of passing an argument or two in MIPS, I'd really appreciate it.  I've found a lot of info on the MIPS calling conventions, but not any simple and succinct examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `lw` which is for extracting words from memory. You can simply use `$a0` in the sub-routine.

Take a look at this example of a "print-char" function:

```
.text

main:

    #save $ra on stack
    addi $sp $sp -4
    sw   $fp 0($sp)
    move $fp $sp
    addi $sp $sp -4
    sw   $ra  -4($fp)

    #call sub-routine
    addi $a0 $zero 'A'
    jal printchar

    #restore and shrink stack
    lw $ra  -4($fp)
    lw $fp   0($fp)
    addi $sp $sp 8

    jr $ra

#prints a char and then a new line
printchar:

    #call print-char syscall
    addi $v0 $zero 11
    syscall

    addi $a0 $zero 10
    syscall

    jr $ra
```

As demonstrated, you the value of the `$a0`  register is just used in the sub-routine as it returns the value that it was given before the `jal`.

Also demonstrated is proper expansion and shrinking of the stack as is necessary for calling a sub-routing. As you will notice, the sub-routine does not perform this operation as it does not call a sub-routine and there-fore does not need to save the `$ra`. Stack manipulations would also be required in the sub-routine if it were to use an `$s` register as the MIPS calling convention specifies these as callee saved.

Comment: Why are you doing manipulations on the stack? is it essential?

Comment: @AsafFisher You must store the value of the `$ra` somewhere when you call a subroutine as `jal` overwrites it.This could be done by using an `$s` register, but I was just demonstrating the general method for saving `$ra` on the stack with manipulation of `$sp` and `$fp`.

Comment: Ok so why not using only sp? Why are you using also fp?

Comment: @AsafFisher Using `$fp`, the frame pointer, allows for dynamic allocation on the stack within the function. I've heard it said that `$fp` is rarely used in hand-written assembly, and you're certainly free to leave it out -- it's not necessary in this example.

Comment: What about if you have to pass in a lot of parameters?

Comment: @KonradLindenbach _Stack manipulations would also be required in the sub-routine if it were to use an $s register as the MIPS calling convention specifies these as caller saved._ I think you mean _callee_ saved here since the function that was called is required to preserve the `$s` registers. Your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111326/mips-assembly-language-temporary-register-vs-saved-registers/20112240#20112240) correctly says "`$s` registers are callee saved."

Comment: @johnktejik See [MIPS function call with moe than four arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298838/mips-function-call-with-more-than-four-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

a very easy way to go about it would be to load the argument in a temp register and then just use:

```
move $a0,$t0
```

this way the argument stored in the temp register will be given as an argument